Why is ScrollTo getting stuck sometimes?
In essence, I have a hero section on my website that has a button at the bottom. The button allows the user to scroll past the hero to the next element automatically.
The Problem: If the user interrupts the animation by scrolling, next time they click the button, the scrolling animation appears stuck - or will only scroll sometimes 10 to 50px instead of the full 100vh.
HTML
<div class="hero-arrow background-colour-ease" id="js-hero-arrow">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" fill="#000000"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M16.59 8.59L12 13.17 7.41 8.59 6 10l6 6 6-6z"/></svg>
</div>

JS
//Hero Arrow Scroll Button
var isScrolling = false;
let B1 = $(".B1");

$(document).on('click', '#js-hero-arrow', function() {

    if (isScrolling === false) {

        isScrolling = true;

        scrollToElementTop(B1).then(() => {
            isScrolling = false;
        });

    }
        
});

//Function to add a callback to the scroll element top
function scrollToElementTop (elem) {

    const targetPosition = (elem.offset().top + elem.outerHeight(true));

    window.scrollTo({
        top: targetPosition,
        behavior: 'smooth'
    });

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const scrollHandler = () => {
            if (window.scrollY === targetPosition) {
                window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler)
                resolve();
            }
        }
        window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler)
    });
}

^ The function "scrollToElementTop" is not mine. I found it on stackoverflow, and hoped that adding the callback and isScrolling would fix my problem, which it did not.
The Questions
Why is this happening and what can I do to fix this?

EDIT:
Without the hack it looked like this:
//Hero Arrow Scroll Button
let B1 = $(".B1");

$(document).on('click', '#js-hero-arrow', function() {

    const targetPosition = B1.offset().top + B1.outerHeight(true);

    window.scrollTo({
        top: targetPosition,
        behavior: 'smooth'
    });
        
});


Can you add a code snippet that does not include your hack (isScrolling and any callbacks)?

looks to me like if your scrolling gets interupted, the promise never resolves, so "isScrolling" is not set to false. You could do the same without javascript using an anchor tag  pointing to the id of what you want to scroll to, and setting css "scroll-behavior: smooth"

Most likely window.scrollY === targetPosition will not pass. The exact scrolling position might vary at the time the event fires. Check if the page was scrolled past the checkpoint instead.

@xuhdev I've updated it for you

I tried replicating the use case with that code and can't see any issues when intentionally interrupting the scrollTo action - is it possible something else in your code is conflicting, or that a second scrollTo action is getting bound/triggered that's interrupting it?

@jmcgriz I've checked for other conflicting code and I can't seem to find anything that would interfere. There are instances of scrollLeft but they're for an unrelated element. The issue I'm having specifically occurs if the user scrolls either up or down before the scrollTo() has completed.

@Teemu seems to have a point. I still think it would be better to remove the js and just to use an anchor link.
